# how to refresh datagrid in windows mobile?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to refresh datagrid in windows mobile? by using c#.

how to clear to datagrid and re bind ?

datagrid bind to table. it is not refreshing when i insert another row

please give any solution for this.

i am writing for binding to datagrid

DataTable dataTable = dsRates.Tables[0];

```
            DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();

            tableStyle.MappingName = dataTable.TableName;

            GridColumnStylesCollection columnStyles = tableStyle.GridColumnStyles;

            DataGridTextBoxColumn columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            columnStyle.MappingName = "MortgageTypeName";
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "Years";
            columnStyle.Width = 58;
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle);

            columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            columnStyle.MappingName = "FixedRate";
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "Fixed(%)";
            columnStyle.Width = 64;
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle);

            columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
            columnStyle.MappingName = "ARMRate";
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "ARM(%)";
            columnStyle.Width = 64;
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle);


            GridTableStylesCollection tableStyles = dgRates.TableStyles;
            tableStyles.Add(tableStyle);


            dgRates.PreferredRowHeight = 16;
            dgRates.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dgRates.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question that needs to be asked is how are you adding the new row to the table?  I have tried your code and everything looks good to me.

I have added new rows to the datatable on a button click and it refreshes the datagrid with no problems

[Sample Project](http://www.mediafire.com/?la2aifv4milg29d)

```
namespace SmartDeviceProject1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataTable.Columns.Add("MortgageTypeName", typeof(String));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("FixedRate", typeof(Int32));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("ARMRate", typeof(Int32));

            DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
            dr["MortgageTypeName"] = "Fixed";
            dr["FixedRate"] = 5;
            dr["ARMRate"] = 10;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle(); 
            tableStyle.MappingName = dataTable.TableName; 

            GridColumnStylesCollection columnStyles = tableStyle.GridColumnStyles; 

            DataGridTextBoxColumn columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn(); 
            columnStyle.MappingName = "MortgageTypeName"; 
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "Years"; 
            columnStyle.Width = 58; 
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle); 

            columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn(); 
            columnStyle.MappingName = "FixedRate"; 
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "Fixed(%)"; 
            columnStyle.Width = 64; 
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle); 

            columnStyle = new DataGridTextBoxColumn(); 
            columnStyle.MappingName = "ARMRate"; 
            columnStyle.HeaderText = "ARM(%)"; 
            columnStyle.Width = 64; 
            columnStyles.Add(columnStyle); 

            GridTableStylesCollection tableStyles = dgRates.TableStyles; 
            tableStyles.Add(tableStyle); dgRates.PreferredRowHeight = 16; 
            dgRates.RowHeadersVisible = false; 
            dgRates.DataSource = dataTable;
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
            dr["MortgageTypeName"] = "Fixed";
            dr["FixedRate"] = 6;
            dr["ARMRate"] = 11;

            dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```